# Do I have two NICs - one for WiFi and one for Wired LAN?

Tags: networking, network-adapter

Similar to most laptops, I have both wifi and wired LAN. Does this mean I have two NICs, or is it one NIC shared between both.

Comment: Two, Zwei, Dos, Ni

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's definitely two NICs. Though they both carry IP as people would expect, they are not the same at the MAC or (especially) PHY layers. Ethernet follows the 802.3 standards; and most people are familiar with the 802.11 standards for WiFi.

Comment: I suppose someone could do something evil with a switch on the MII bus to make it talk to different PHYs, but I've never seen this myself...

Comment: s/evil/awesome/

Answer (score 1):

Pull up a linux terminal and type `ifconfig -a` for all the gory details.  If on Windows, pull up a command prompt and type `ipconfig /all`.

Comment: That's `ipconfig -a` for a Windows box... The default output of `ifconfig` on *nix boxen usually shows all the most pertinent details.

Comment: doh. clicked over here from serverfault, did not realize I had switched to superuser. still assuming *nix. :)